# How to fix HDFS org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem not found

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am trying to load files to HDFS 
This is what I am trying to do before the copyFromLocalFile command

```
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", getHDFSDefaultName());    
conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
conf.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

This is the exception that i am getting

```
...
at com.bigid.scanner.hive.HiveJDBCConnector.isJarListPathEnabled(HiveJDBCConnector.java:865)
    at com.bigid.scanner.hive.HiveJDBCConnector.getTables(HiveJDBCConnector.java:700)
    at com.bigid.scanner.hive.HiveJDBCConnector.access$400(HiveJDBCConnector.java:45)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2197)
```

I saw similar threads regarding this subject but none of the suggestions there worked - adding jar files to the pom and setting fs.xxxx.impl params.
Also tried to load classes using classLoader with no success, 
This works in my code environment but note as an application.

Comment: in which context are you trying to run this code?? What are you meaning when you say application?

Comment: I mean to say when i run it from intelliJ, it is working. When I run it as web server, issuing commands to the hive server, it throws this error. 
Not sure what goes wrong with the class loader

Comment: are you using thrift server??

Comment: No I create a jar out of my application load it to tomcat, and try to connect to Hive server with it.

Comment: hmmm, what about load the jar in the classpath?? have you tried that?